# Why does sip complain about unexpected type 'str' when using a char *?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, python-sip, python-bindings

I am trying to use sip to create python bindings from c++ to python 3.8.
[I found a simple example here](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_cpp_sip.php)
and updated it to get it working with sip version 5.4 which I installed with pip.
[Details can be found here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/sip/index.html)

I changed the names from word to basicword because I rewrote and tested the word example with strings. To do that I had to write a bunch of sip specific code to get the import of the string library working and thought there must be an easier way.

I was under the assumption, that using a char * (like in the original tutorial) would be 'easier' for sip, what am I missing?

My sip file basicword.sip:

```
// Define the SIP wrapper to the basicword library.

%Module(name=basicword, language="C++")

class Basicword {

%TypeHeaderCode
#include <basicword.h>
%End

public:
    Basicword(const char *w);

    char *reverse() const;
};
```

My pyproject.toml file:

```
# Specify sip v5 as the build system for the package.
[build-system]
requires = ["sip >=5, <6"]
build-backend = "sipbuild.api"

# Specify the PEP 566 metadata for the project.
[tool.sip.metadata]
name = "basicword"

# Configure the building of the basicword bindings.
[tool.sip.bindings.basicword]
headers = ["basicword.h"]
include-dirs = ["."]
libraries = ["basicword"]
library-dirs = ["."]
```

My basicword.h file:

```
#ifndef BASICWORD_H
#define BASICWORD_H


// Define the interface to the basicword library.

class Basicword {

private:
    const char *the_word;

public:
    Basicword(const char *w);

    char *reverse() const;
};


#endif //BASICWORD_H
```

My basicword.cpp file:

```
#include "basicword.h"

#include <cstring>

Basicword::Basicword(const char *w) {
    the_word = w;
}

char* Basicword::reverse() const {
    int len = strlen(the_word);
    char *str = new char[len+1];
    for(int i = len-1;i >= 0 ;i--) {
        str[len-1-i] = the_word[i];
    }
    str[len+1]='\0';
    return str;
}
```

My file test.py:

```
from basicword import Basicword

w = Basicword("reverse me") // -> error thrown here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(w.reverse())
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path to testfile>/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    w = Basicword("reverse me")
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  Basicword(str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  Basicword(Basicword): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

Thank you for your answer!

Bye Johnny

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full and complete error. And if there's a reference to a file and line, then please add a comment in that file and on that line to show where you get the error.

Comment: sorry forgot the testfile and the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short Python2 uses str-type by default and python3 byte-type so I had to change default encoding for python3.

I found the relevant detail [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/sip/annotations.html#argument-annotation-Encoding)

> Encoding
>
> ```
> This string annotation specifies that the corresponding argument (which should be either char, const char, char * or const char *)
> ```
>
> refers to an encoded character or '\0' terminated encoded string with
> the specified encoding. The encoding can be either "ASCII", "Latin-1",
> "UTF-8" or "None". An encoding of "None" means that the corresponding
> argument refers to an unencoded character or string.
>
> ```
> The default encoding is specified by the %DefaultEncoding directive. If the directive is not specified then None is used.
>
> Python v3 will use the bytes type to represent the argument if the encoding is "None" and the str type otherwise.
>
> Python v2 will use the str type to represent the argument if the encoding is "None" and the unicode type otherwise.
> ```

With the following simple addition in basicword.sip ...

```
// Define the SIP wrapper to the basicword library.

%Module(name=basicword, language="C++")

%DefaultEncoding "UTF-8" // Missing Encoding!

class Basicword {

%TypeHeaderCode
#include <basicword.h>
%End

public:
    Basicword(const char *w);

    char *reverse() const;
};
```

everything works now.